# Put request getting 404 status while trying to update datadog dashboards

Tags: python, request, http-status-code-404, put

```py
r2 = requests.put('https://app.datadoghq.com/dashboard/{dashboardID}', data=dataset)
print(r2)
```

```
--->>  <Response [404]>
```

I think I need to add some kind of identification user/pass, api_key/app_key, right? I am not sure how I am adding the body into the requests. Can somebody explain briefly about it and share some examples of identification and body of the `put()` call?

when trying to use the `get()` call it works and responds with a `[200]` status:

```py
r3 = requests.get("https://app.datadoghq.com/dashboard/{dashboardID}")
print(r3)
```

```
--->>  <Response [200]>
```

Comment: Did you try to read the docs - [Update a dashboard](https://docs.datadoghq.com/api/latest/dashboards/#update-a-dashboard)?

Comment: {"errors":["The value provided for parameter 'dashboard_list_id' is invalid"]}%                                         ..... I am getting this error any Idea where to find this dashboardID or list_id mentioned here https://docs.datadoghq.com/dashboards/guide/dashboard-lists-api-v1-doc/?tab=curl#get-items-of-a-dashboard-list

Answer (score 0):

You need to put in the api key/app key.
You might try

```
requests.put('https://app.datadoghq.com/dashboard/{dashboardID}?api_key={api_key}&application_key={app_key}', data=dataset)
```